# Saving the file with Dataframe.to_csv but read_csv gets type error

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv

I save my dataframe as such:

```
df_train.to_csv('df_train.csv',index = False)
!cp df_train.csv "drive/My Drive/"
```

I print the dtypes to make sure of the column types

```
id                           int64
user_name                   object
user_location               object
user_description            object
user_created                object
user_followers               int64
user_friends                 int64
user_favourites              int64
user_verified                 bool
date                datetime64[ns]
text                        object
hashtags                    object
source                      object
retweets                     int64
favorites                    int64
is_retweet                    bool
sentiment                   object
clean_text                  object
```

If I read the file afterwards without specifying dtype I **think** I get the correct values read, and the process completes fine without errors or warnings **but** all columns of the new dataframe are of type 'object'.

```
df_train = pd.read_csv('drive/My Drive/df_train.csv')
```

If I read it with dtypes however I get this error:  **invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'doses '**

```
train_types = {
    'id':  'int64',
    'user_name':  'object',
    'user_location':  'object',
    'user_description':  'object',
    'user_created':  'object',
    'user_followers':  'int64',
    'user_friends':  'int64',
    'user_favourites':  'int64',
    'user_verified':   'bool',
    'date':   'datetime64[ns]',
    'text':  'object',
    'hashtags':  'object',
    'source':  'object',
    'retweets':  'int64',
    'favorites': 'int64',
    'is_retweet':  'bool',
    'sentiment':  'object',
    'clean_text':  'object'
}
#df_train = pd.read_csv('drive/My Drive/df_train.csv')
df_train = pd.read_csv('drive/My Drive/df_train.csv', dtype=train_types,parse_dates=['date'],low_memory=False,index_col=0)
```

This makes me believe there is something wrong with the types. If it is any help I believe this 'doses ' comes from the last column of a row and then it proceeds to read the 'id' from the next row which is 'int' hence the error.
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: _invalid literal for `int()` with base 10: `'doses '`_ -> Have you checked in which column the item `'doses '` is located?

Comment: Could it be that you accidentally read an old file?

Comment: @Timus there are many (700+) 'doses ' items but as I mentioned it is most possibly on the last column 'clean_text' and the reading crashes coz it goes to read an 'int' for the id that is the first column of the next line

Comment: But if that is the error you get then it is the _first_ issue it encounters? And it is at odds with `... 'clean_text':  'object' ..`?